# Why isn't my mongoose sort method working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

All right. So. I have a really basic API running on Node.js. I'm also using MongoDB as a database and I'm using Mongoose to build queries. My problem is that I'm trying to query for a sorted list of data using using the mongoose 'sort' method. For some reason the method isn't working and Node tries to use the Javascript sort method instead. This is my code:

**Query handling:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const express = require("express");
const Tour = require("../models/tourModel.js");

exports.getAllTours = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line node/no-unsupported-features/es-syntax
    const queryObject = { ...req.query };
    const excludedFields = ["page", "sort", "limit", "fields"];
    excludedFields.forEach((el) => delete queryObject[el]);

    let queryStr = JSON.stringify(queryObject);
    queryStr = queryStr.replace(/\b(gte|gt|lte|lt)\b/g, (match) => `$${match}`);

    let query = await Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

    // query.sort((a, b) => (a[req.query.sort] > b[req.query.sort] ? 1 : -1));
    if (req.query.sort) {
      query = query.sort(req.query.sort);
    }

    const tours = await query;

    res.status(200).json({
      status: "success",
      data: { tours },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ status: "failed", message: error.message });
  }
};
```

**Router**

```
const tourController = require("../controllers/tourController");

const router = express.Router();

// router.param("id", tourController.checkID);

router
  .route("/")
  .get(tourController.getAllTours)
  .post(tourController.createTour);

router
  .route("/:id")
  .get(tourController.getTourById)
  .patch(tourController.updateTour)
  .delete(tourController.deleteTour);

module.exports = router;
```

**Package.json**

```
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "fdsfd",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "start:prod": "nodemon server.js NODE_ENV=production "
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.12.7",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.25.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

When I try to query for `127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/tours?sort=price`,
I get a response

```
{
    "status": "failed",
    "message": "The comparison function must be either a function or undefined"
}
```

I'm a real noob in this so does anyone have any ideas what is causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you deleting sort from the query parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let query = await Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));
```

This is the **result** of your query since await executes the query. If you want to store the query, don't use `await`

```
let query = Tour.find(JSON.parse(queryStr));

// query.sort((a, b) => (a[req.query.sort] > b[req.query.sort] ? 1 : -1));
if (req.query.sort) {
  query = query.sort(req.query.sort);
}

const tours = await query;
```